# Why does a chain riveter have 2 separate pins to hold the chain

Tags: repair, tools

My (broken) chain riveter has 4 pins to hold the chain[image: Chain riveter]

I always used the 2 on the left side since there is the possibility to apply counter-pressure with the screw. What is the purpose of the right pins?

(Please correct me if I used the wrong word for the tool)

Comment: The screw to apply counterpressure has a hole so the left pins can be used to push the pin out too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to a [couple](https://youtu.be/Ap-pQwzn6Vw?t=94) of [videos](https://youtu.be/wr3GfSrL68k?t=11) I found online, the left - in your photo - "shelf" (or "cradle") is for pushing a pin out or pushing a new pin in.  The right (closer to the screw) shelf is for loosening a tight link.

Comment: You're exactly right, is for "loosening" a pin - this situation can happen if one reconnects a chain and it is not moving freely, resulting in a "stiff link" which interferes with shifting and can make clonking noises every 4-8 pedal strokes.    Personally I fix a stiff link by putting my thumbs on it and "bending" the chain sideways with hand pressure, which has generally been enough with a push-pull.  Ideally a chain should be floppy.

Comment: @Criggie Yeah that's how I've always tackled a stiff chain too; of course my chain tool doesn't have a fancy feature specifically for that. :D